# Hardwired Programmable Mouse

Tags: mice

I would like a mouse that has copy and paste solely programmed into it.

The peculiarity about this is I don't what a mouse that simply has buttons but has the keyboard shortcuts programmable into the mouse.

The big advantage of this for me is that I can use it on linux/mac/windows machines with out any additional software.

Edit: So apparently the keyboard shortcuts are hardware wired based on the configuration software often but not always.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seDYxGhrc4A  This gives me some hope of getting one that works for all 3 operating systems ideally.  I have messed with Karabiner Elements on macOS and can likely get that one to at least partially work.  He is using the AJazz GTX mouse.

Comment: I don't believe any mouse exists that has pure hardware copy and paste functionality. Most people just use macros on gaming mice for things like this. For example, a [mouse like this one](https://www.amazon.com/VicTsing-Ergonomic-Programmable-Windows-Backlit/dp/B07B7CZ9Y8) that explicity supports windows/mac/windows should get the job done. Note: Not necessarily best price or best mouse, example mouse purely for argumentative purposes.

Comment: I have messed with Linux and it's mapping software tends to be lacking in my experience for a system wide copy and paste if it isn't hard wired.

Comment: The mouse I linked you would theoretically handle driver-os mapping with its own vendor based software.

Comment: @BennettYeo " Note: the programming function and side buttons are not available for Mac OS, but the other function can be used normally."  If it doesn't support Mac OS have to also wonder about linux.

Comment: Missed that, I also did a little more digging and it seems most programmable mice only support windows, or support windows/linux exclusively. It appears to be very hard to cull mice based on 'programmable' and triple OS support for keymapping software.

Comment: I looked up a few logitech programmable mice with linux/windows keymap support, and found some forums claiming that they were able to load the macros in on windows and take it over to Linux. I just can't personally endorse a mouse with those assumptions in full confidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms a fairly cheap option, take a look at the Logitech G203.  I like it because it has six buttons but looks like a regular mouse(not the gaming mice).

It works in Linux & Windows as long as you configure it in Windows initially.  I'm not sure about macOS.

Comment: If it works like this it most likely has internal memory to remember the shortcuts so it should work on macOS too... Although the shortcuts/keycodes might be different.

Comment: Yeah I'll test when I get access to our Mac.  My intuition tells me the windows key shortcut will most likely work correctly.